# It is possible to manually sort files inside the atom left panel?

Tags: atom-editor

Sometimes i feel the need to place the files from a folder in the order i want.

By default they are sorted alphabetically - maybe because of how the `OS` is ordering them - but i expect `atom` to be able to move them around - if i install the appropriate package.

[image]

I couldn't find anything yet. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Your best bet is probably to file a feature request.